# I am tried accessing the next line and compared with current line in java arraylist object using stream.reduce.not able to achive it getting error

Tags: java

I am trying to compare and print only the unique value from the each line of getprice() as below:

```
List<Model> results = lists.stream()
    .reduce((c1,c2) -> c1.getprice() != c2.getprice()? c1:c2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

  //The Object is like this:

      object[{type:1,price:20},
             {type:2,price:30}
             {type:3,price:30}
             {type:4,price:60}
            ];
  //OUTPUT expected after reducing the duplicate value of price

//object[{type:1,price:20},{type:2,price:30},{type:4,price:60}
            ];
```

I am trying to compare and print only the unique value from the each line from arraylist which is getprice.

//The Object is like this:

```
  object[{type:1,price:20},
         {type:2,price:30}
         {type:3,price:30}
         {type:4,price:60}
        ];
```

OUTPUT expected after reducing the duplicate value of price

> object[{type:1,price:20},{type:2,price:30},{type:4,price:60}
>               ];

Comment: Are you sure that this is valid java code? Because reduce is terminal operation

Comment: @slesh.Yes I am sure.If you know any otherway using java stream please try it out with my code

Comment: So, you're sure of what you're doing, yet you have an error, and you're asking us about it, but you won't post it to let us know what it is? I wouldn't disregard sjesh's comment if I were you. Read the error message you get. Read the javadoc.

Comment: @JB Nizer.i already i got the output...It is kind of learning i am doing.Nothing wrong in posting in place where people can learn....this question really will help many people.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you obviously want to use Java 8 `Stream`  API one Solution might be to group your list by `price` and then filter your returned value `Collection` with `List.size() >= 1` because i assume each type should have a price and if not we can ignore it.

Then stream your `price List` again and perform `findFirst();`

Here an example:

```
models.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Model::getPrice)).values().stream()
        .filter(modelWrapperList -> modelWrapperList.size() >= 1).forEach(modelList -> {
  modelList.stream().findFirst().ifPresent(results::add);
});
```

But a much simpler solution would be to keep track of your already added `prices` and filter your `List` based on it.

Another Example:

```
Set<Integer> existingPrices = new HashSet<>();

results = models.stream().filter(model -> existingPrices.add(model.getPrice()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Thank you works like charm Paku580.I am new to stream.Started learning.It is great learning from you.

Comment: ,And also we can get unique values using . distinct () predict..... it is much easier.no need to even use Map... distinct simplyfies....

Comment: I am not quite sure if this is correct. Assuming you have a `List` of type `Model` then `models.stream().distinct()` will return you a Stream of distinct `Models`. Now it could be a different `Model` but with the same value of the `price` property. Hence the duplicate would still be present in your `List`. But if it would be the same `Model Object` then you are right and could just call `distinct()`.

Comment: :this will work:List<Integer> arr= lists.stream()
          .map(e -> e.getPrice())
             .distinct()
          .collect(Collectors.toList());